# Split RNN Memory Consumption Evenly Between GPUs in TensorFlow

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, tensorflow, gpu, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to figure out the most strategic way to evenly split the memory load of a seq2seq network between two GPUs.

With convolutional networks, the task is much easier. However, I'm trying to figure out how to maximize the memory usage of 2 Titan X's. The goal is to build the largest network that the combined 24GB of memory will allow.

One idea was to place each RNN layer in a separate GPU.

```
GPU1 --> RNN Layer 1 & Backward Pass
GPU2 --> RNN Layer 2,3,4
```

However, the backprop computations require a significant amount of memory. Therefore, another idea is to do the entire forward pass on one GPU and the backward pass on the separate GPU.

```
GPU1 --> Forward Pass
GPU2 --> Backward Pass
```

(However, GPU2 still takes most of the memory load)

Is there any way to measure how much of the GPU memory is being used? This would allow us to figure out how to maximize each GPU before it's "filled up".

Once 2 GPUs are used, I would eventually want to use four. However, I think maximizing 2 GPUs is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "colocate_gradients_with_ops" as TRUE maybe work. It allows GPU memory to allocated evenly.

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gvs, global_step=self.global_step)
```